# Manter meu aplicativo checando por atualizações do WebService

Tags: android

Então, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Supondo que eu tenha uma lista `RecycleView` de usuários em meu aplicativo, onde esta lista é preenchida através de uma requisição ao meu `WebService`.

Gostaria que meu aplicativo ficasse 'checando' quando um novo usuário é adicionado no servidor e avisa-se ao meu aplicativo.

Qual caminho devo seguir?

O que exatamente devo estudar? Services? Content Provider? Boradcast Recivers? ou outra coisa?

Comment: Android Push Notifications recorrendo ao Google Cloud Messaging GCM. Veja [aqui](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_%28GCM%29_-_PART_1/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139) um exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Tenho caso parecido e vou soluciona-lo com https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Basicamente, é um serviço que permite o envio de mensagens do servidor para o dispositivo móvel e do dispositivo para o servidor.